# excel formula for multiplying columns

Tags: mac

I am looking for formula in which if I am multiplying Two columns like Column A and Column C (Column B is blank)and result is coming in Column D and i drag this formula for all row's below, and suppose if in next row Column A is blank and Column B is there than it should automatically multiple Column B with Column C to get result in Column D

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Apple products.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (on D1):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1) * C1
```

Which check is A1 is empty, if so it makes B1*C1, if not then it makes A1*C1.

(As I'm not in an English version of Excel, the names may vary)

Comment: Its not working, can you please give me another formula or may be explain this one

Comment: am using in english language and am using mac excel 2011

Comment: =ISBLANK(A1) is working and showing whether its true or flase

Comment: but when i am using =IF(ISBLANK(A1);B1;A1) its showing that the formula i have type contains an error

Comment: DO I HAVE TO PUT FORMULA LIKE THIS =IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1)A1*C1 OR =IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1)B1*C1

Comment: @sumit just like this : `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1) * C1`

Comment: can u help me with another thing ...i have to combine three columns into one column.. for that i got the concatenate formula but i want to combine these column with line break ..for CHAR(13) formula is not working ..do you have any idea about this

Comment: for e.g.:- A1=riley, B1=456, C1=NEW YORK D1=Pin Code=CONCATENATE("The ", A2, " Family", CHAR(13), B2, CHAR(13), C2, ", ", D2, " ", E2)

Comment: I mean i want to show name and address of person in one single cell with next line but all this information is in different column and i want to combine all this in one column with line break

Comment: @sumit Try `A1=riley, B1=456, C1=NEW YORK D1=Pin Code` and `F1=CONCATENATE("The ", A1, " Family", CHAR(10), B1, CHAR(10), C1, ", ", D1, " ", E1)

Comment: i have tried with CHAR(10) but it was not working so i tried CHAR(13) because when i searched on google it was mention to use CHAR(13) instead of CHAR(10) for mac excel

Comment: @sumit then I don't know :)

Comment: and do you know if there is any formula suppose if in Column there is particulars like H H H S S H S H  and in end i want to see total amount of H and S separate ..can i automatically show in end

Comment: @sumit see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187667

Comment: what i meant to ask suppose i have purchase apple 50kg for $50 and grapes 20 kg for $30 and orange 10kg for $15 and am doing this daily and in end of month i want to see separate kg's and amount for whole month and later year of apple, grapes and orange without sorting it

Comment: can you guide for using combo box in mac excel to create drop down suggestion list

Comment: @sumit you should learn on your own or you'll never be better. BTW, this is not how ask different works. You should take a look a that link : http://www.microsoft.com/mac/how-to/excel

Comment: actually i tried to search myself and found this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185388... and tried to do as mentioned in step but am not to get that drop down suggestion list ..i would be very great full if can help me with this last problem